# How to populate a list of suggestions in textbox in Android

Tags: android, mysql, android-studio

I have an array "array_topic_names" of some string values(which is being retrieved by the database) and I want to populate it as a list of suggestions in my textbox.

Android Code:

```
public class create_form extends Activity implements OnItemSelectedListener, AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

private AutoCompleteTextView edttxt1 = null;
    private AutoCompleteTextView edt1 = null;
    private AutoCompleteTextView edt3 = null;
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)

    {
      edttxt1 = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.edttxt4);//topic1
      edt1 = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.edttxt2);//topic2new PostAsync2().execute();
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      edt3 = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.edttxt45);//topic3

      setContentView(R.layout.activity_create_form);

      adapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, array_topic_names);

        edttxt1.setThreshold(1);
        //Set adapter to AutoCompleteTextView
        edttxt1.setAdapter(adapter2);
        edttxt1.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        edttxt1.setOnItemClickListener(this);

        edt1.setThreshold(1);
        //Set adapter to AutoCompleteTextView
        edt1.setAdapter(adapter2);
        edt1.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        edt1.setOnItemClickListener(this);

        edt3.setThreshold(1);
        //Set adapter to AutoCompleteTextView
        edt3.setAdapter(adapter2);
        edt3.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        edt3.setOnItemClickListener(this);
}
class PostAsync2 extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject> {

        JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

        private ProgressDialog pDialog;

        private static final String LOGIN_URL = "http://10.0.3.2/topic_array_populate.php";


        private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
        private static final String TAG_MESSAGE = "message";


        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            Log.d("preexec", "starting");

        }

        @Override
        protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {

            try {

                HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();

                JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                        LOGIN_URL, "POST", params);


                if (json != null) {
                    Log.d("JSON result", json.toString());
                    return json;
                }



            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {

            int success = 0;
            String message = "";

            Log.d("post exec", "starting");

            Log.d("json", json.toString());

            if (pDialog != null && pDialog.isShowing()) {
                pDialog.dismiss();
            }

            if (json != null) {
                {
                    Log.d("json", "not null");

                    JSONArray data = null;
                    try {
                        data = json.getJSONArray("details");

                        Log.d("JSON result",json.toString());
                        for(int i=0;i<100;i++) {
                            JSONObject obj = data.getJSONObject(i);
                            Log.d("obj_value", obj.toString());
                            array_topic_names[i]=obj.toString().substring(15).replace("}","").replace("\"","");
                            Log.d("array_topic_names", array_topic_names[i]);
                        }



                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                try {
                    success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                    message = json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }


    }
}
```

LOGCAT

```
06-27 13:52:47.812 11218-11218/com.example.somya.client_feedback_application D/post exec: starting
06-27 13:52:47.814 11218-11218/com.example.somya.client_feedback_application D/json: {"details":[{"topic_name":"abc"},{"topic_name":"xyz"},{"topic_name":"bbb"},{"topic_name":"ccc"},{"topic_name":"1a"},{"topic_name":"2b"},{"topic_name":"3c"}]}
06-27 13:52:47.814 11218-11218/com.example.somya.client_feedback_application D/json: not null
06-27 13:52:47.814 11218-11218/com.example.somya.client_feedback_application D/JSON result: {"details":[{"topic_name":"abc"},{"topic_name":"xyz"},{"topic_name":"bbb"},{"topic_name":"ccc"},{"topic_name":"1a"},{"topic_name":"2b"},{"topic_name":"3c"}]}
06-27 13:52:47.814 11218-11218/com.example.somya.client_feedback_application D/obj_value: {"topic_name":"abc"}
06-27 13:52:47.814 11218-11218/com.example.somya.client_feedback_application D/array_topic_names: abc
06-27 13:52:47.814 11218-11218/com.example.somya.client_feedback_application D/obj_value: {"topic_name":"xyz"}
06-27 13:52:47.814 11218-11218/com.example.somya.client_feedback_application D/array_topic_names: xyz
06-27 13:52:47.814 11218-11218/com.example.somya.client_feedback_application D/obj_value: {"topic_name":"bbb"}
06-27 13:52:47.814 11218-11218/com.example.somya.client_feedback_application D/array_topic_names: bbb
06-27 13:52:47.814 11218-11218/com.example.somya.client_feedback_application D/obj_value: {"topic_name":"ccc"}
06-27 13:52:47.814 11218-11218/com.example.somya.client_feedback_application D/array_topic_names: ccc
06-27 13:52:47.814 11218-11218/com.example.somya.client_feedback_application D/obj_value: {"topic_name":"1a"}
06-27 13:52:47.814 11218-11218/com.example.somya.client_feedback_application D/array_topic_names: 1a
06-27 13:52:47.814 11218-11218/com.example.somya.client_feedback_application D/obj_value: {"topic_name":"2b"}
06-27 13:52:47.814 11218-11218/com.example.somya.client_feedback_application D/array_topic_names: 2b
06-27 13:52:47.814 11218-11218/com.example.somya.client_feedback_application D/obj_value: {"topic_name":"3c"}
06-27 13:52:47.814 11218-11218/com.example.somya.client_feedback_application D/array_topic_names: 3c
```

I want each value in array array_topic_names to populate as a suggestion in my text box.How can I do it?
Right now,there is no error,but also no suggestion list is shown.
And also when hardcoded that array,it was working,after I retrieved it from the database,its not working.

Comment: i think you forgot to notify the adapter after updating the adapter. Add this code to your onPostExecute after for iterator 'adapter2.notifyDataSetChanged(); '

Comment: @AnkushBist Where am I supposed to call the PostAsync.execute() ?

Comment: @AnkushBist I added it,But it didn't help.

Comment: please update your answer. For more help try to check log and add log after and before the adapter notify. You may also debug the code to track the issue.

Comment: The parsing is not accurate. You should do a traversal of your JSONArray.